# SignalR Chat Application User defined ConnectionId is not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub

I'm new to signalR and angularJS. I recently developed chat application using signalR and angularJs in asp.net MVC5 .

I changed Context.ConnectionId to User logged in Id. So each refresh, ConnectionId wont refresh. I can view all logged in/online users , i can send messages by selected users,but receiver can't see the messages sent by sender.

In ChatHub.cs

```
public void SendPrivateMessage(long toUserId, string message,long connid)
        {
            long fromUserId =Convert.ToInt32(connid);
            var toUser = loggedInUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId);
            var fromUser = loggedInUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);
            if (toUser != null && fromUser != null)
            {
               // 
                Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(toUserId, fromUser.Username, message);
                Clients.Client(Convert.ToString(toUserId)).sendPrivateMessage(fromUserId, fromUser.Username, message);
            }
        }
```

In Controler.js

```
signalR.RecievingPrivateMessage(function (toname, fromname, msg) {


            console.log($scope.ShowPrivateWindow == false);
           if ($scope.ShowPrivateWindow == false) {
                $scope.ShowPrivateWindow = true;
            }
           // var msgBdy = { room: r, msgx: { message: msg.message, sender: msg.sender, css: msg.css } };
            //$scope.chatHistory.push(msgBdy);
            $scope.PrivateMessages.push({ to: toname, from: fromname, message: msg });
            console.log($scope.PrivateMessages);
            if ($scope.$parent.UserName != fromname) // otheruser's pm
            {
                console.log('here');
                if ($scope.UserInPrivateChat == null)
                {
                    $scope.UserInPrivateChat = { Username: fromname, ConnectionId: toname }
                }
            }
            /// To Scroll the message window.
            if ($("#PrivateChatArea div.panel-body").length == 1) {
            var    $container = $("#PrivateChatArea div.panel-body");
                $container[0].scrollTop = $container[0].scrollHeight;
                $container.animate({ scrollTop: $container[0].scrollHeight }, "fast");
            }
            $scope.$evalAsync();
           // $scope.AddMessageToRoom(msgBdy);
        });
```

What will be the problem here? I'm not able to track the mistakes.